# Postioning drowndown menu under their parent li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a small but an annoying issue. I want the sub menus to be displayed under each submenu's parent's `li`.

- Right now each submenu when hovered over the parent shows under the
  FIRST `li` item.

**Attempt:** I've made `.main-navigation ul` `position relativ`e while `.main-navigation ul ul` is positioned absolute - please see the code. Ideas?

```js
(function($) {


  /* NAVIGATION ON CLICK */
  // Primary menu drop down (mobile)
  $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu:first").toggleClass("toggle-on");
  });


  /* NAVIGATION ON HOVER */
  // Sub menu drop down 
  // $(".main-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children").hover(function() {
  //  $(this).find(".sub-menu:first").toggleClass("toggle-on");
  // });

  var menu_timeout;

  $(".main-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children").hover(
    function() { // Mouseenter
      var that = $(this);
      that.find(".sub-menu:first").addClass("toggle-on");
      clearTimeout(menu_timeout);
    },
    function() { // Mouseleave
      var that = $(this);
      menu_timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        that.find(".sub-menu:first").removeClass("toggle-on");
      }, 250);
    }
  );

  /* submenu click mobil version */
  $(".menu-toggle").click(function() {
    $(" .main-navigation ul:first").toggleClass("toggle-on");
  });

  // $(".main-navigation li.menu-item-has-children").mouseleave(function() {
  //   $(".sub-menu").removeClass("toggle-on");
  // });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
*,
html {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.site-header {
  width: 100%;
  /*min-height: 99px;*/
  background-color: #0b80c3;
  z-index: 100;
}

.header-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1920px;
  margin: auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .site-header {
    position: fixed;
  }
  .header-wrap {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .site-branding {
    margin-left: 2.5rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1922px) {
  .header-wrap {
    left: 0;
  }
}


/* Burger Nav Styling */

#sidebar-btn {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 40px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}

#sidebar-btn span {
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar-btn span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 75%;
}

#sidebar-btn span:nth-child(3) {
  width: 50%;
}


/* Main Menu */

.main-navigation {}

.fa-caret-down {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-test-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 145px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.main-navigation .menu.toggle-on {
  display: block;
}

.main-navigation ul {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

.main-navigation ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 20px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .main-navigation ul li {
    padding: 15px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .main-navigation ul li {
    padding: 20px;
  }
}

.main-navigation ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 467px) {
  .main-navigation ul li:hover {
    background-color: none;
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul li {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 468px) {
  .main-navigation ul li:hover {
    background-color: #ffcc33;
  }
}


/* SUB Menu styles */

.sub-menu.toggle-on {
  display: block;
}

.main-navigation ul,
.main-navigation ul ul,
.main-navigation ul ul ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}


/* Positioning x y of EACH sub menus */

.main-navigation ul ul {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

.main-navigation ul ul li:hover,
.main-navigation ul ul li:focus {
  background-color: black;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 468px) {
  .main-navigation ul ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 75px;
    min-width: 200px;
    background-color: #0c7cbc;
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul li:hover {
    background-color: #ffcc33;
  }
}

.main-navigation ul ul ul {
  left: 150px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.main-navigation ul ul ul ul {
  background-color: green;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
}

.main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul {
  background-color: black;
  top: 0px;
  left: 200px;
}

.main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul ul {
  background-color: silver;
  top: 0px;
  left: 200px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 468px) {
  .header-wrap {
    flex-direction: column;
    /*padding: 0 1rem;*/
  }
  .site-title {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  /* Main Navigation - Getting rid of navburger */
  #sidebar-btn {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .main-navigation .menu.toggle-on {
    display: flex;
    /*   background-color: blue;
*/
  }
  .main-navigation ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #0b80c3;
  }
  .menu-test-container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
  }
  /* end of */
  /* Sub menu navigation tablet */
  /* Positioning x y of EACH sub menus */
  .main-navigation ul ul {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul li {
    padding: 7px 1px;
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul li a {
    font-size: 90%;
    padding: 10px 10px;
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul ul {
    left: 6.4rem;
    top: 5px;
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul ul ul {
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul {
    top: 0px;
    left: 141px;
  }
  .main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul ul {
    top: 0px;
    left: 200px;
  }
}


/* TABLET MENU */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .header-wrap {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .site-title {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  /* Main Navigation - Getting rid of navburger */
  #sidebar-btn {
    display: none;
  }
  .primary-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .main-navigation .menu.toggle-on {
    display: flex;
  }
  .main-navigation ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .menu-test-container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
  }
  /* end of HEADER */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
  <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
  <div class="menu-test-container">
    <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-2035" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/"><span data-hover="Services">Services</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-2076" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/project/"><span data-hover="Commercial">Commercial</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-2082" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/project/"><span data-hover="Rural">Rural</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu toggle-on">
          <li id="menu-item-2079" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/gallery/"><span data-hover="Residential">Residential</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-2084" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/project/"><span data-hover="Projects">Projects</span></a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-2045" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/blog/"><span data-hover="Blog">Blog</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-2081" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/"><span data-hover="Electrical">Electrical</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-2078" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/"><span data-hover="About">About</span></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-2099" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/"><span data-hover="News Updates">News Updates</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**insert this to code:**

```
ul li {
    position: relative;
}
```

```js
    (function($) {
 

 /* NAVIGATION ON CLICK */
// Primary menu drop down (mobile)
$( ".dropdown-toggle" ).click(function() {
 $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu:first" ).toggleClass("toggle-on");
  });


/* NAVIGATION ON HOVER */
// Sub menu drop down 
 // $(".main-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children").hover(function() {
 //  $(this).find(".sub-menu:first").toggleClass("toggle-on");
 // });

var menu_timeout;

$(".main-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children").hover(
  function(){  // Mouseenter
    var that = $(this);
    that.find(".sub-menu:first").addClass("toggle-on");
    clearTimeout(menu_timeout);
  },
  function(){  // Mouseleave
    var that = $(this);
      that.find(".sub-menu:first").removeClass("toggle-on");
  }
);

/* submenu click mobil version */
$(".menu-toggle").click(function() {
  $(" .main-navigation ul:first").toggleClass("toggle-on");
});

// $(".main-navigation li.menu-item-has-children").mouseleave(function() {
//   $(".sub-menu").removeClass("toggle-on");
// });



 
})( jQuery );
```

```css
  *, html {
   margin: 0;
   font-size: 22px;
  }
  .site-header {
   width: 100%;
   /*min-height: 99px;*/
     background-color: #0b80c3;
     z-index: 100;
  }
  .header-wrap {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
     padding: 0 20px;
     width: 100%;    
  max-width: 1920px;
  margin:auto;
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
   .site-header {
    position: fixed;
   }

   .header-wrap {
      top: 0;
      left:0;
      right: 0;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
   }

   .site-branding {
    margin-left: 2.5rem;
   }
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 1922px) {
   .header-wrap {

      left:0;

   }
  }

 /* Burger Nav Styling */
 #sidebar-btn {
   vertical-align: middle;
   width: 40px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin:10px;
   position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  
 }
 #sidebar-btn span {
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
 }
 #sidebar-btn span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 75%;
 }
 #sidebar-btn span:nth-child(3) {
  width: 50%;
 }


  /* Main Menu */
  .main-navigation {
  }

   .fa-caret-down {
   color: #fff;
  }

 .menu-test-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 145px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;

 }
 .main-navigation .menu.toggle-on {
  display: block;
 }

  .main-navigation ul {
   display: none;
      position: relative;

   }

  .main-navigation ul li  {
   border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
   padding: 20px; 
  }


  @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
   .main-navigation ul li  {
    padding: 15px;
   }

  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
   .main-navigation ul li  {
    padding: 20px;

   }
  }
    .main-navigation ul li a {
     color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;

    }


  @media screen and (max-width: 467px) {
   
   .main-navigation ul li:hover {
     background-color: none;
   }
   .main-navigation ul ul li {
    border-bottom: none;
   }

  }
  
  @media screen and (min-width: 468px ) {
   .main-navigation ul li:hover {
     background-color: #ffcc33;
   }    
  }

 /* SUB Menu styles */
  .sub-menu.toggle-on {
   display: block; 
  }

  .main-navigation ul, .main-navigation ul ul, .main-navigation ul ul ul  {
   list-style: none;
   display: none;

      margin-left:0;
     padding-left:0;
  }

 /* Positioning x y of EACH sub menus */
 .main-navigation ul ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 10px;
    min-width: 200px;    
    background-color: black;
  }  
  .main-navigation ul ul li:hover, .main-navigation ul ul li:focus  {
      background-color: black;
  } 

 @media screen and (min-width: 468px ) {
  .main-navigation ul ul {
     position: relative;
     left: 0;
     top: 75px;
     min-width: 200px;
     
     background-color: #0c7cbc;
    }
    .main-navigation ul ul li:hover  {
     background-color: #ffcc33;
    }


 }


   .main-navigation ul  ul ul {
    left: 150px;
    top: 0;
    background-color: inherit;
    }

    .main-navigation ul ul ul ul {
     background-color: green;
     top: 20px;
     left: 0;
    }
    .main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul {
     background-color: black;  
     top:0px;
     left: 200px;
   }
     .main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul ul {
     background-color: silver;  
     top:0px;
     left: 200px;
   }

 @media  only screen and (min-width: 468px) {
 .header-wrap {
  flex-direction: column;
  /*padding: 0 1rem;*/
  }

   .site-title {
   margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  /* Main Navigation - Getting rid of navburger */
  #sidebar-btn {
   display: none;
  }

  .menu-toggle {
   display: none;
  }

  .main-navigation .menu.toggle-on {
   display: flex;
/*   background-color: blue;
*/  }
  .main-navigation  ul {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: space-between;
   background-color: #0b80c3;
  }

  ul li {
   position: relative;
  }

  .menu-test-container {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
  } /* end of */

     /* Sub menu navigation tablet */
   /* Positioning x y of EACH sub menus */
    .main-navigation ul ul {
     position: absolute;
      }


      .main-navigation ul ul li {
       padding: 7px 1px;
      }

      .main-navigation ul ul li a {
       font-size: 90%;
           padding: 10px 10px;

      }

    .main-navigation ul  ul ul {
     left: 6.4rem;
     top: 5px;
     }

     .main-navigation ul ul ul ul {
      top: 35px;
      left: 0;
     }
     .main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul {
      top:0px;
      left: 141px;
    }
      .main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul ul {
      top:0px;
      left: 200px;
    }
 }

  /* TABLET MENU */  
 @media  only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .header-wrap {
  flex-direction: row;

 }
  .site-title {
      margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  
  /* Main Navigation - Getting rid of navburger */
  #sidebar-btn {
   display: none;
  }

  .primary-toggle {
   display: none;
  }

  .main-navigation .menu.toggle-on {
   display: flex;
  }
  .main-navigation  ul {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   flex-direction: row;
   margin: 0;
   justify-content: space-between;
 
  }
  .menu-test-container {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
  } 



  /* end of HEADER */
   


 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
    <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
    <div class="menu-test-container"><ul id="primary-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-2035" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/"><span data-hover="Services">Services</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-2076" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/project/"><span data-hover="Commercial">Commercial</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-2082" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/project/"><span data-hover="Rural">Rural</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu toggle-on">
 <li id="menu-item-2079" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/gallery/"><span data-hover="Residential">Residential</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-2084" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/project/"><span data-hover="Projects">Projects</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-2045" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/blog/"><span data-hover="Blog">Blog</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-2081" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/"><span data-hover="Electrical">Electrical</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-2078" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/"><span data-hover="About">About</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-2099" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/"><span data-hover="News Updates">News Updates</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>    
   </nav>
```

**Updated post :**

Change `mouse leave` event like this:

```
  function(){  // Mouseleave
    var that = $(this);
      that.find(".sub-menu:first").removeClass("toggle-on");
  }
```

Comment: Perfect. Quick question: Once your mouse leaves the parent li the submenu should hide (As attempted in my javascript code for mouseleave event. However right now, if I hover over different parent menus quick they all open and don't close quick. How can I fix this?

Comment: @Shaz , 250ms is long time in `Mouseleave` ,use of 10.see my update post

Comment: Ok will do, but again, the mouseleave function is not exactly correct: When you hover over a parent li from another parent li the latter submenu doesn't close! even after changing - how to fix this? please

Comment: it working well,can you clear it with an example.please!

Comment: Hover over services then quickly hover over Blog and About, their submenu's are all open. (Services submenu should have closed when you hovered over Blog and About.) Problem only when you hover over li when sub menu

Comment: Yes! It worked. the darn thing was cached so I couldn't tell. So the speed is to 0 by default in the mouse leave function? And the trick was to have position relative on .main-navigation ul li

Answer (score 0):

You have to add position: relative; to .main-navigation ul li

```js
(function($) {
 

 /* NAVIGATION ON CLICK */
// Primary menu drop down (mobile)
$( ".dropdown-toggle" ).click(function() {
 $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu:first" ).toggleClass("toggle-on");
  });


/* NAVIGATION ON HOVER */
// Sub menu drop down 
 // $(".main-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children").hover(function() {
 //  $(this).find(".sub-menu:first").toggleClass("toggle-on");
 // });

var menu_timeout;

$(".main-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children").hover(
  function(){  // Mouseenter
    var that = $(this);
    that.find(".sub-menu:first").addClass("toggle-on");
    clearTimeout(menu_timeout);
  },
  function(){  // Mouseleave
    var that = $(this);
    menu_timeout = setTimeout(function(){
      that.find(".sub-menu:first").removeClass("toggle-on");
    },250);
  }
);

/* submenu click mobil version */
$(".menu-toggle").click(function() {
  $(" .main-navigation ul:first").toggleClass("toggle-on");
});

// $(".main-navigation li.menu-item-has-children").mouseleave(function() {
//   $(".sub-menu").removeClass("toggle-on");
// });



 
})( jQuery );
```

```css
*, html {
   margin: 0;
   font-size: 22px;
  }
  .site-header {
   width: 100%;
   /*min-height: 99px;*/
     background-color: #0b80c3;
     z-index: 100;
  }
  .header-wrap {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
     padding: 0 20px;
     width: 100%;    
  max-width: 1920px;
  margin:auto;
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
   .site-header {
    position: fixed;
   }

   .header-wrap {
      top: 0;
      left:0;
      right: 0;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
   }

   .site-branding {
    margin-left: 2.5rem;
   }
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 1922px) {
   .header-wrap {

      left:0;

   }
  }

 /* Burger Nav Styling */
 #sidebar-btn {
   vertical-align: middle;
   width: 40px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin:10px;
   position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  
 }
 #sidebar-btn span {
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
 }
 #sidebar-btn span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 75%;
 }
 #sidebar-btn span:nth-child(3) {
  width: 50%;
 }


  /* Main Menu */
  .main-navigation {
  }

   .fa-caret-down {
   color: #fff;
  }

 .menu-test-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 145px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;

 }
 .main-navigation .menu.toggle-on {
  display: block;
 }

  .main-navigation ul {
   display: none;
      position: relative;

   }

  .main-navigation ul li  {
   border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
   padding: 20px; 
      position: relative;
  }


  @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
   .main-navigation ul li  {
    padding: 15px;
   }

  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
   .main-navigation ul li  {
    padding: 20px;

   }
  }
    .main-navigation ul li a {
     color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;

    }


  @media screen and (max-width: 467px) {
   
   .main-navigation ul li:hover {
     background-color: none;
   }
   .main-navigation ul ul li {
    border-bottom: none;
   }

  }
  
  @media screen and (min-width: 468px ) {
   .main-navigation ul li:hover {
     background-color: #ffcc33;
   }    
  }

 /* SUB Menu styles */
  .sub-menu.toggle-on {
   display: block; 
  }

  .main-navigation ul, .main-navigation ul ul, .main-navigation ul ul ul  {
   list-style: none;
   display: none;

      margin-left:0;
     padding-left:0;
  }

 /* Positioning x y of EACH sub menus */
 .main-navigation ul ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 10px;
    min-width: 200px;    
    background-color: black;
  }  
  .main-navigation ul ul li:hover, .main-navigation ul ul li:focus  {
      background-color: black;
  } 

 @media screen and (min-width: 468px ) {
  .main-navigation ul ul {
     position: relative;
     left: 0;
     top: 75px;
     min-width: 200px;
     
     background-color: #0c7cbc;
    }
    .main-navigation ul ul li:hover  {
     background-color: #ffcc33;
    }


 }


   .main-navigation ul  ul ul {
    left: 150px;
    top: 0;
    background-color: inherit;
    }

    .main-navigation ul ul ul ul {
     background-color: green;
     top: 20px;
     left: 0;
    }
    .main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul {
     background-color: black;  
     top:0px;
     left: 200px;
   }
     .main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul ul {
     background-color: silver;  
     top:0px;
     left: 200px;
   }

 @media  only screen and (min-width: 468px) {
 .header-wrap {
  flex-direction: column;
  /*padding: 0 1rem;*/
  }

   .site-title {
   margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  /* Main Navigation - Getting rid of navburger */
  #sidebar-btn {
   display: none;
  }

  .menu-toggle {
   display: none;
  }

  .main-navigation .menu.toggle-on {
   display: flex;
/*   background-color: blue;
*/  }
  .main-navigation  ul {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   justify-content: space-between;
   background-color: #0b80c3;
  }

  .menu-test-container {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
  } /* end of */

     /* Sub menu navigation tablet */
   /* Positioning x y of EACH sub menus */
    .main-navigation ul ul {
     position: absolute;
      }


      .main-navigation ul ul li {
       padding: 7px 1px;
      }

      .main-navigation ul ul li a {
       font-size: 90%;
           padding: 10px 10px;

      }

    .main-navigation ul  ul ul {
     left: 6.4rem;
     top: 5px;
     }

     .main-navigation ul ul ul ul {
      top: 35px;
      left: 0;
     }
     .main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul {
      top:0px;
      left: 141px;
    }
      .main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul ul {
      top:0px;
      left: 200px;
    }
 }

  /* TABLET MENU */  
 @media  only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .header-wrap {
  flex-direction: row;

 }
  .site-title {
      margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  
  /* Main Navigation - Getting rid of navburger */
  #sidebar-btn {
   display: none;
  }

  .primary-toggle {
   display: none;
  }

  .main-navigation .menu.toggle-on {
   display: flex;
  }
  .main-navigation  ul {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   flex-direction: row;
   margin: 0;
   justify-content: space-between;
 
  }
  .menu-test-container {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
  } 



  /* end of HEADER */
   


 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
    <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
    <div class="menu-test-container"><ul id="primary-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-2035" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/"><span data-hover="Services">Services</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-2076" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/project/"><span data-hover="Commercial">Commercial</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-2082" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/project/"><span data-hover="Rural">Rural</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu toggle-on">
 <li id="menu-item-2079" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/gallery/"><span data-hover="Residential">Residential</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-2084" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/project/"><span data-hover="Projects">Projects</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-2045" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/blog/"><span data-hover="Blog">Blog</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-2081" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/"><span data-hover="Electrical">Electrical</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-2078" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/"><span data-hover="About">About</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-2099" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/"><span data-hover="News Updates">News Updates</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>    
   </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, since your menu is based simply on the CSS :hover pseudo-class, make sure that your ul and li elements do not have any space between them, because this will lead to the entire menu dissapearing.

Just like the drop down that you already provided, simply adding a ul element within the li element should suffice to create the sub menu. I added a nav_menu_sub class to the li that opens the sub menu making it easier to select via CSS (avoiding .nav_menu ul li ul li).

```css
.nav_menu {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    z-index:2000;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.selected {
    background-color:#ccc;
    color:#333;
}
.nav_menu a:link {
    color:#007dc1;
}
.nav_menu a:visited {
    color:#007dc1;
}
.nav_menu a:hover {
    color:#007dc1;
}
.nav_menu ul {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.nav_menu ul li {
    font-size:16px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 8px 22px;
    font-weight:600;
    transition: all 50ms linear;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
.nav_menu ul li ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 37px;
    left: 0;
    width: 230px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
    z-index:50000;
}
.nav_menu ul li ul li {
    background-color:#535353;
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
    display: block; 
    font-size:12px;
    color:#fff;
}
.nav_menu ul li ul li:hover {
    background: #B2B2B2; 
}
.nav_menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    background-color:red;
}

.nav_menu_sub ul {
    margin-top:-7px;
    display: none !important;
}

.nav_menu_sub:hover ul {
    display: block !important;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;  
}
```

```html
<div class='nav_menu'>
    <ul>
     <li>All Items
       <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li class='nav_menu_sub'>Item 3 with Sub Menu
          <ul>
            <li>SubItem 3.1</li>
            <li>SubItem 3.2</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
       </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The margin-top:-7px on the ul element was added to ensure that it fits nicely up against the li.

Add the !important to the display attribute to get it overwrite the previously declared styling.

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/akhrbkug/

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://codepen.io/Shuree/pen/MQagaj)

```
<ul class="root">
    <li>
      Services
    </li>
  <li>
    Rural
    <ul class="child">
      <li>CHILD 1</li>
      <li>CHILD 2</li>
      <li>CHILD 3</li>
      <li>CHILD 4</li>
      <li>CHILD 5</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Projects
  </li>
  <li>
    Blog
  </li>
  <li>
    About
  </li>
</ul>
```